# Tensorflow MultiRNNCell save and restore

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, load, recurrent-neural-network

It seems like either saving or restoring the model with MultiRNNCell is not working properly.

I was working on classification problem by using below code;

```
stacked_rnn_cell = list()
for i in range(config.num_layers):
    rnn_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units=config.dim_hidden)
    stacked_rnn_cell.append(rnn_cell)
rnn_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(cells=stacked_rnn_cell, state_is_tuple=True)
```

And I used rnn_cell(stacked) to train and saved the model.

In my case, I trained for two models: one with num_layers = 2, the other with num_layer = 3.

And then, I run the above code first then do the restore procedure to replace the weight values to the variables above.

It seems like it only loads the first layer of the rnn_cell since loading with num_layers = 1 gives exactly same result as the one with the model num_layers = 2, or num_layers = 3.

Model itself is loaded well so I can only think that it is not saved or loaded properly.

=====
Edited: I loaded without any matching model and used the code below to see

```
tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES)
```

Then the output is

```
[<tf.Variable 'global_step:0' shape=() dtype=int32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'embedding_layer/w:0' shape=(11441, 200) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/fw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/kernel:0' shape=(400, 800) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/fw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/bias:0' shape=(800,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/fw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/lstm_cell/kernel:0' shape=(400, 800) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/fw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/lstm_cell/bias:0' shape=(800,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/fw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_2/lstm_cell/kernel:0' shape=(400, 800) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/fw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_2/lstm_cell/bias:0' shape=(800,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/bw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/kernel:0' shape=(400, 800) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/bw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/bias:0' shape=(800,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/bw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/lstm_cell/kernel:0' shape=(400, 800) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/bw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/lstm_cell/bias:0' shape=(800,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/bw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_2/lstm_cell/kernel:0' shape=(400, 800) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/bw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_2/lstm_cell/bias:0' shape=(800,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/attn/w1:0' shape=(400, 400) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/attn/w2:0' shape=(400, 400) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/attn/w3:0' shape=(400, 1) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/attn/b2:0' shape=(400,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/attn/concat_w:0' shape=(800, 400) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'logits/w:0' shape=(800, 7) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'logits/b:0' shape=(7,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'train_optimizer/beta1_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'train_optimizer/beta2_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'embedding_layer/w/Adam:0' shape=(11441, 200) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'embedding_layer/w/Adam_1:0' shape=(11441, 200) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/fw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/kernel/Adam:0' shape=(400, 800) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/fw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/kernel/Adam_1:0' shape=(400, 800) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/fw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/bias/Adam:0' shape=(800,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/fw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/bias/Adam_1:0' shape=(800,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/fw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/lstm_cell/kernel/Adam:0' shape=(400, 800) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/fw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/lstm_cell/kernel/Adam_1:0' shape=(400, 800) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/fw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/lstm_cell/bias/Adam:0' shape=(800,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/fw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/lstm_cell/bias/Adam_1:0' shape=(800,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/fw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_2/lstm_cell/kernel/Adam:0' shape=(400, 800) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/fw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_2/lstm_cell/kernel/Adam_1:0' shape=(400, 800) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/fw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_2/lstm_cell/bias/Adam:0' shape=(800,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/fw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_2/lstm_cell/bias/Adam_1:0' shape=(800,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/bw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/kernel/Adam:0' shape=(400, 800) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/bw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/kernel/Adam_1:0' shape=(400, 800) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/bw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/bias/Adam:0' shape=(800,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/bw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/bias/Adam_1:0' shape=(800,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/bw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/lstm_cell/kernel/Adam:0' shape=(400, 800) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/bw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/lstm_cell/kernel/Adam_1:0' shape=(400, 800) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/bw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/lstm_cell/bias/Adam:0' shape=(800,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/bw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/lstm_cell/bias/Adam_1:0' shape=(800,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/bw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_2/lstm_cell/kernel/Adam:0' shape=(400, 800) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/bw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_2/lstm_cell/kernel/Adam_1:0' shape=(400, 800) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/bw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_2/lstm_cell/bias/Adam:0' shape=(800,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/bw/multi_rnn_cell/cell_2/lstm_cell/bias/Adam_1:0' shape=(800,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/attn/w1/Adam:0' shape=(400, 400) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/attn/w1/Adam_1:0' shape=(400, 400) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/attn/w2/Adam:0' shape=(400, 400) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/attn/w2/Adam_1:0' shape=(400, 400) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/attn/w3/Adam:0' shape=(400, 1) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/attn/w3/Adam_1:0' shape=(400, 1) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/attn/b2/Adam:0' shape=(400,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dynamic_rnn/attn/b2/Adam_1:0' shape=(400,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'logits/w/Adam:0' shape=(800, 7) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'logits/w/Adam_1:0' shape=(800, 7) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'logits/b/Adam:0' shape=(7,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'logits/b/Adam_1:0' shape=(7,) dtype=float32_ref>]
```

which means that it stored correctly as it was intended, using three hidden layers of rnn cells. But it seems like weights does not match to the models automatically with this multi hidden layers.

=====

I tried to find the save and restore of the model using deep rnn, but I couldn't find any so I am asking here to get some help.

Anyone had the same problem and solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can change "tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell" to "tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell"